# search for string in json file

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

i have a dictionary which the user enters values in at the beginning, those values are then stored into a txt file in json format. The goal is for the user to be able to search the json file with a string of their choice. I have tried a variety of ways but have come up unsuccesful. The code below shows if the user enters 's' then they will be prompted to enter a search term. the code then loads the json file and stores the information from the file into a "list" called "data", then the code attempts to search every item within the list and compare it to the searchTerm inputted from the user

code that puts the users input into the txt file (json format)

```
if choice == 'a':
    # Add a new joke.
    # See Point 3 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    jokeSetup = input('Enter setup of joke: ')
    jokePunchLine = input('Enter puncline of joke: ')
    entry = {'setup': jokeSetup , 'punchline': jokePunchLine}
    data.append(entry)
    file = open('data.txt', 'w')
    json.dump(data, file)
    file.close()
    print('Joke Added.')
    pass


elif choice == 's':
    # Search the current jokes.
    # See Point 5 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    searchTerm = input('Enter search term: ')
    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)
    file.close()

    for item in data:
        if searchTerm in data:
            print ('found it')


    pass
```

Comment: what is the format of your data ? Can you show us an example?

Comment: @quemeraisc this is the format for the dictionary i load into the json file       entry = {'setup': jokeSetup , 'punchline': jokePunchLine}

Comment: You should close the file after you are finished searching it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
import sys
import os
data = []
if os.stat("data.txt").st_size != 0 :
    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)
    print(data)

choice = input("What's your choice ?")
if choice == 'a':
    # Add a new joke.
    # See Point 3 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    jokeSetup = input('Enter setup of joke: ')
    jokePunchLine = input('Enter punchline of joke: ')
    entry = {'setup': jokeSetup , 'punchline': jokePunchLine}
    data.append(entry)
    file = open('data.txt', 'w')
    json.dump(data, file)
    file.close()
    print('Joke Added.')
    pass


elif choice == 's':
    # Search the current jokes.
    # See Point 5 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    searchTerm = input('Enter search term: ')
    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)
    file.close()

    for sub_dict in data:
        if searchTerm in sub_dict['setup']:
            print(sub_dict['punchline'])
    pass
# or you could modify the last for loop, like this:
    for dict in data:
        if searchTerm in dict['setup'] or searchTerm in dict['punchline']:
            print('found!')
    pass
```

Comment: or something like this, according to what you want
    for sub_dict in data:
        if searchTerm in sub_dict['setup'] or searchTerm in     sub_dict['punchline']:
            print('found!')

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
if choice == 'a':
# Add a new joke.
# See Point 3 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    jokeSetup = input('Enter setup of joke: ')
    jokePunchLine = input('Enter punchline of joke: ')
    entry = {'setup': jokeSetup , 'punchline': jokePunchLine}
    data.append(entry)
    file = open('data.txt', 'w')
    json.dump(data, file)
    file.close()
    print('Joke Added.')
    pass

elif choice == 's':
    # Search the current jokes.
    # See Point 5 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    searchTerm = input('Enter search term: ')
    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)
    file.close()

    for item in data[0].items():
        if searchTerm in str(item[1]):
            print ('found it')

    pass

# or the for loop could be like this
for sub_dict in data:
    if searchTerm in sub_dict['setup'] or searchTerm in sub_dict['punchline']:
        print('found!')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: What is the format of your data? The above code works for me considering that json example.

Comment: entry = {'setup': jokeSetup , 'punchline': jokePunchLine}     that is the dictionary that im dumping into the json file @Jomy Emmanuel

Comment: i have added some more code to the post to show how i get the users input into the txt file (json format)

Comment: I have edited my answer. Instead of appending entry to data, you could directly do json.dump(entry, file). In such a case, there is no need for data[0].items(), rather data.items() should work.

Comment: if i directly use json.dump(entry, file) and use data.items() instead of appending i get the error i posted earlier. if i use your data[0].items() solution i dont get any results (print 'fount it'), even if i search a term that i know is within the json file

Comment: Seems strange. I have tested your code in my computer and it worked perfectly fine for me. What does printing data[0].items() show?

Comment: well if i search the term "wh" it prints 'found it' but if i search "why" it dosnt print anything. even though you can clearly see "why" is in the json file

Comment: that stops it from even finding "wh", the solution before could find "wh" but not "why". i have tryed search other terms aswell, but i havnt found any yet that get the code to print 'found it'

Comment: Could you tell the inputs you tried for both jokeSetup and jokePunchLine and searchTerm?